# ColorThief react library not rendering

Tags: reactjs, color-thief

I'm using ColorThief library in react. Here's my code:

```
   import Color from 'color-thief-react';

   mappedPopularBooks = Object.keys(popularBooks).map(key => {
                var book = popularBooks[key];
                return <Color src={book.image}>
                    {({data, loading, error}) => (
                        <div style={{
                            backgroundColor: data,
                            backgroundSize: "91px 141px",
                            backgroundPosition: "center center",
                            backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                            backgroundImage: "url('" + book.image + "')"
                        }} className="Home-item" key={`popular-${key}`}>
                            {data}
                        </div>
                    )}
                </Color>
            });
```

The backgroundColor is not being set. What should I do?

Comment: Quick questions, can you please share where from Color is being imported? and what is the console.log for `data`? a runnable code will be really helpful for me to troubleshoot.

Comment: I'm confused about why you're mapping the keys and then accessing the same object to get the book. Why not `popularBooks.map(book => {})`?